# R Test if Lists Contain String

Tags: r, list

I have a string of numbers, and a list:

```
 a <- c(1,2,3)
 b <- list( x<-c(1:5),y<-c(1:10),z<-c(10:20))
```

What I want to do is to test whether each number is in each element of the list -- whether 1 is in x, 2 is in y, 3 is in z. And then give 1/0 to a new variable.

My code:

```
d <- ifelse(a %in% sapply(b,function(x) unlist(x)),1,0)
```

However the result:

```
> d
[1] 0 0 0
```

And desirable result should be:

```
[1] 1 1 0
```

How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: You should probably use `=` instead of `<-` within the `list` call, or `x`, `y`, and `z` will also be assigned as variables (unless that's what you intended, of course). To be clear, for `a` and `b` both are fine.

Answer (score 9):

You're looping over two matching sets of data, which suggests `Map/mapply`:

```
mapply(`%in%`, a, b)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

as.integer(mapply(`%in%`, a, b))
#[1] 1 1 0
```

Comment: OMG, I spent a whole day figuring this out, and I got your answer in 5min. Another question: in this case, if the list contains 'NA', then the result is 'FALSE', how to let it return 'NA' instead? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ElmerLI - you can write a little wrapper function - `mapply(function(v,l) if(is.na(l[1]) & length(l)==1) NA else v %in% l, a, b)`

Answer (score 2):

It is worth noting that `is.element` is the equivalent of `%in%`, so you can avoid typing some quotation marks. If you like `purrr`, you can get the right answer with

```
map2_int(a,b, is.element)

[1] 1 1 0
```

Comment: The `sapply` one has different logic; it would return `TRUE` for the second element even if there was no 2 in the second element of `b` as long as there was a 1 or 3. You could make an equivalent version by `sapply`ing over a sequence to index both with, but that's not great practice. The `is.element` bit is interesting, though; I haven't used that.

Answer (score 2):

The `purrr` package has a number of variations on the `*apply` family and helper functions useful for working with lists. In this case, it would look like

```
library(purrr)

map2_int(a, b, ~.x %in% .y)    # shorthand for map2_int(a, b, function(x, y){x %in% y})
## [1] 1 1 0
```

or

```
map2_int(a, b, `%in%`)
## [1] 1 1 0
```

where

- the `map` part is the name of a set of functions that apply a function to the elements of a list,
- the `2` part is a version that takes two lists as input and iterates over them in parallel, and
- the `_int` part is a version that simplifies the result to an integer vector.

Comment: This is so educational. You are amazing! Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, but seems more convoluted that the answer from thelatemail.

Comment: It's more or less the same; `map2` is directly equivalent to `Map`. I'm not sure this approach is preferable unless you're doing prior or further list manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to mimic a `for loop` with `apply` functions is to actually define an iterator.

`sapply(1:length(b), function(i) a[i] %in% b[[i]])`

This will return booleans
`[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE`

convert to int with `as.integer()`

I feel like this is more intuitive than `mapply`, and with a self-defined function call, you can tweak around with it, say making a `if` statement searching for `NA` lists.